# SQL server DB connection from .net 2010

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to connect to SQL server running on a VM Image with the C# program from my laptop.

my connection string look like the following

```
   conn.ConnectionString =
            @"Data Source=192.168.22.182;" +
            "Initial Catalog=master;" +
            "User id=sa;" +
            "Password=livelink;"+
            "Connection Timeout=30";
   conn.Open();
```

i always got this error!

***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)***

I also tried using the name of the VM machine, but still got the same error.

Please help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: Can you connect to the database by any other means?  Can the computer running this code connect to the computer running the database?  If this is a networking or VM configuration issue then perhaps Server Fault would be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

First check these:

1. Make sure that you are reaching that ip from your local machine.
2. Make sure that your VM is not blocking SQL Server's port which is 1433 on default.
3. Try this connection string:

   conn.ConnectionString =
                   @"Data Source=192.168.22.182,1433;" +
                   "Initial Catalog=master;" +
                   "User id=sa;" +
                   "Password=livelink;"+
                   "Connection Timeout=30";
          conn.Open();

"," value is the port value for SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you Tough Coder! the port 1433 is blocked in my VM image when i opened that its works fine. thank you again for the help